# Installing Magento2 extension without using command line

Tags: magento2

I have downloaded a Magento2 extension in zip format. I have access to the FTP; but not command line in server. How this can be installed without using command line tools?

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/quick-tour/install-extension.html this one will help for you

Comment: Just curious, why can you enter commands? Do you have an SFTP access?